# Amino acid vs. amino-acid

Tags: hyphenation, science

In the following two examples, is there any difference as to how *amino acid* should be hyphenated?

- There are twenty **amino acids**.
- The **amino acid** content is 80%.

My intuition would be to hyphenate in the second example (where *amino acid* is a modifier) and not in the first, but I couldn't back it up.

Is there a general rule that would apply?

Comment: Google *hyphen* to verify your intuition.

Comment: @RichardKayser As a chemist you should know that some people use "amino-acids" indiscriminately.

Comment: Googling "amino acid content" shows a reasonably even split between the hyphenated and unhyphenated forms. The rule 'hyphenate compounds when used to pre-modify' is nowadays usually relaxed by adding 'if this adds clarification'. I wouldn't, here.

Comment: Not trying to look smart. Just suggesting that you do some research on the use of hyphens before coming here. You can't go wrong with no hyphen in your first example and hyphen in you second example. Agree with @EdwinAshworth's comment on your second example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your intuition is correct.

According to the International Union of Pure and Applied Chemistry's [Guide to Nomenclature and Symbolism for Amino Acids and Peptides](http://www.chem.qmul.ac.uk/iupac/AminoAcid/AA1n2.html):

> When the phrase 'amino acid' is a qualified noun it contains no hyphen; a hyphen is inserted when it becomes an adjective so as to join its components in qualifying another noun, e.g. amino-acid sequence

Comment: And, indeed, this is generally good practice. Why? Because it can prevent ambiguity ‘false scent’, especially where nouns are being used as adjectives.

Comment: Yes, but this is a domain-specific guide and not binding to general English usage. There was a dog's breakfast a few tears ago when the BrE spelling of _sulphur_ had to be marked wrong in science exams in the UK, but the AmE (and IUPAC) spelling had to be marked wrong in English exams. ELU is not science-orientated, so here, either spelling is acceptable.